# Chrome extensions new tab as window popunder

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a new window from a recently opened tab. The code that i currently have creates a new tab, then creates a new chrome window out of it , but the window is in a foreground despite being not focused. How do I make it appear in a background?

Here is my current code:

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url: url, active: false }, function (newTab) {
    chrome.windows.create({
        tabId: newTab.id,
        type: 'popup',
        focused: false,
        // incognito, top, left, ...
    }, function (window) {
        window.focused = false;
    });
});
```

Comment: set [`WindowState`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#type-WindowState) to `minimized` may be a workaround.

Comment: @HaibaraAi unfortunately no, cause i need this window to be of 1px x 1px size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
chrome.windows.create({
    tabId: newTab.id,
    type: 'popup',
    focused: true,
    // incognito, top, left, ...
}, function (window) {
  chrome.windows.update(window.id, {focused:true});
});
```

Comment: I edited your answer - after that it will work correctly.